# XML data import in Excel

Tags: xml, excel, xml-parsing, xsd

I have a huge XML which I want to import in excel. Here is a piece of the XML which I want to import.

```
<ROOT>
  <ELEMENTS>
    <ELEMENT1>
      <A>1</A>
      <B>2</B>
      <C>3</C>
    </ELEMENT1>
    <ELEMENT2>
      <A>3</A>
      <B>2</B>
      <C>1S</C>
    </ELEMENT2>
  </ELEMENTS>
</ROOT>
```

When I import this XML to Excel I see headers as `A`, `B` and `C`, but I don't get `ELEMENT1` and `ELEMENT2` as headers.
What am I doing wrong here? My XML structure is nice and I am getting a well parsed XML.

Comment: What does your Xsd schema for this import look like? Afaik Excel can't really handle hierarchical data and hence restricts importing to the leafs (A, B and C in your case) mapped to columns.

Comment: I dont have any XSD schema for import, and I don't know how to specify Xsd for import

Comment: would you like to try out [this](https://github.com/amolpujari/reading-huge-xml/blob/master/examples/item.rb) option in ruby

Answer (score 0):

Column is A,B,C
Row is each member of element

Effectively Excel expects a two dimensional arrary rows and columns.

No idea what you want to achieve, but trying

```
<ROOT>
  <ELEMENTS> 
    <ELEMENT> 
      <TYPE>1</TYPE>
      <A>1</A> 
      <B>2</B> 
      <C>3</C> 
    </ELEMENT> 
    <ELEMENT> 
      <TYPE>2</TYPE>
      <A>3</A> 
      <B>2</B>
      <C>1S</C> 
    </ELEMENT> 
  </ELEMENTS> 
</ROOT>
```

Should be instructive

Comment: I need 2 level header like under Element1 we will have A B C and in Element2 we have A B C and so on....

Comment: It doesn't do hierarchical. Use something like my suggestion to get the data into a hidden worksheet, and then pull the data out of that in the format you want should be doable.